# ITMS-90745: Invalid Toolchain

Tags: xcode, app-store

Uploading to App Store Connect works fine until publishing for review with the App Store.

On xcode 11.3 Beta, the most up to date.

Email includes;

> ITMS-90745: Invalid Toolchain - Your app was built with a version of
>   Xcode or SDK that is not yet supported. For information about the
>   supported version of Xcode or SDK for App Store submissions, view
>   Apple Developer News and Updates (https://developer.apple.com/news/).

I can upload just fine and use TestFlight just fine.

What is the max x-code version for uploading binary to the app store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a beta version for uploading apps to the app store.

Since Apple doesn't provide support for beta builds on the app store, you need to upload using xcode 10 until xcode 11 comes out of beta.

The beta allows testing through testflight but your binary will always be rejected whilst on a new beta.

Tl;dr. Always use the most up to date version available on the Mac App Store when wanting to upload to the app store.

Answer (score 0):

User Xcode 11.2.1 GM. Hope it will work.